# SQLiteSwift Filtering issues

Tags: swift, sqlite, filtering

yesterday I started working with Databases for my App. I have my database with SQLiteSwift. I have created a simple DB (id, name, last name) and I do a select and it shows every row stored in the table. The problem is, when I want to filter by ID, I get nothing and the App shows the following error...

[image]

I think there is no problem with the DB because I tried some querys with DB Browser for SQLite. Probably this is a problem with my var *filter*.

My code is the following...

```
    func filterQuery(filter: String) {
    do {
        for personas in try db!.prepare(self.tblPersona) {
            print("ID: \(personas[id]), Nombre: \(personas[nombre]!), Apellido: \(personas[apellido]!)")
        }
         print("SELECTED USER:")
         let res = Int64 (filter)
         print(tblPersona.filter(id == res!) )
        }
    catch {
        print("No se pudo obtener informacion")
    }
}
```

Comment: I called this function using an action button with this code:  `DatabaseManagement.shared.filterQuery(filter: filtro.text!)` from my DatabaseManagement Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out, I just did a prepare statement for the Database.

```
   print("SELECTED USER:")
        let res = Int64 (filter) 
        let query = tblPersona.filter(id == res!)
        for user in try db!.prepare(query) {
            print(user[nombre]!)
            print(user[apellido]!)
        }
```